# Specifying date in robocopy destination folder

Tags: windows-server-2008, scripting, robocopy, command-line-interface

I would like to specify the date via CLI when running robocopy so that the destination folder includes the date.

```
robocopy C:\folder\ Z:\folder_DATE /E /ZB /COPYALL /NP /V /LOG:F:\backup_log.txt
```

Where DATE is the current date. Is this possible or would I have to resort to power shell?

I found this [Stack Overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-usi) but am looking to keep it simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't really say what the format of the date you wanted, so I'm going by yyyymmdd. That'll probably suit sorting better as the days, months and years go on.

```
FOR /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %date%') DO SET datevar=%%c%%b%%a
robocopy C:\folder\ Z:\folder_%datevar% /E /ZB /COPYALL /NP /V /LOG:F:\backup_log.txt
```

You can change the date however you want with the %%c being the year %%b being the month and %%a being the day. Just reorder them to your need.

Comment: The format you suggested is fine and thanks for the explanation. I am getting the following error when entering the first line **%%a was unexpected at this time.**

Comment: Command line you will need a single %, if you put it in a script you'll need to keep the double %%.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%A in ('date /T') DO (
robocopy C:\folder\ Z:\folder_%%A-%%B-%%C /E /ZB /COPYALL /NP /V /LOG:F:\backup_log.txt
)
```

Comment: If you can use like this: _for /f "delims=" %%a in (serversToUpdate.txt) do_ ?